# How to display Google Sheet in HTML format using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I would like to display a list of hotels in HTML using data from this Google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pksFEATRRWfOU27kylZ1WLBJIC-pMVxKk9YlCcDG0Kk/

I am using JSON and jQuery, and would like to use jQuery to loop over all of the rows, displaying them in HTML format.

So far I have managed to display some content using JSON but I am unsure how to proceed with displaying all of the rows:
Codepen: http://codepen.io/aljohnstone/pen/adobow

```
$.getJSON('http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pksFEATRRWfOU27kylZ1WLBJIC-pMVxKk9YlCcDG0Kk/od6/public/values?alt=json',function(data){
//remove http:// for a text
var url = data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$url']['$t'];
var shortUrl = url.replace('http://', '');
//give id's google sheet values
$('#bandb').text(data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$name']['$t'])
$('#description').text(data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$description']['$t'])
$('#image').attr("src", (data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$image']['$t']));
$('#link').text(shortUrl).attr("href", (data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$url']['$t']));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery `foreach`

```
    $.getJSON('http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pksFEATRRWfOU27kylZ1WLBJIC-pMVxKk9YlCcDG0Kk/od6/public/values?alt=json',function(data){
    $.each(data.feed.entry,function(i,v){

var url = v.gsx$url.$t;
    var shortUrl = url.replace('http://', '');
     var data = $('<div class="listing">').append('<img src="'+v.gsx$image.$t+'" id="image"/><h4 id="bandb">'+v.gsx$name.$t+'</h4><p id="description">'+v.gsx$description.$t+'</p><a href="'+v.gsx$url.$t+'" id="link">'+shortUrl+'</a>');
      $('body').append(data);
    });

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVbypE?editors=001

Comment: This is a great answer. Perhaps it is what OP really wants, I was just focusing on the general iterating issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a great way of doing what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a front-end templating framework, such as [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/). There are a lot of options in this area. What you will typically do in a templating framework is define an HTML template that uses placeholders for your data. Then, in your javascript, you'll pass the data object into the templates. Here's how it might look in mustache:

**Template**

```
<script id="listing-template" type="text/html">
    <div class="listing">
        <img class="image" src="{{gsx$image.$t}}"/>
        <h4 class="bandb">{{gsx$name.$t}}</h4>
        <a class="link" href="{{gsx$url.$t}}">{{gsx$url.$t}}</a>
        <p class="description">{{gsx$description.$t}}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>

    $.getJSON('http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pksFEATRRWfOU27kylZ1WLBJIC-pMVxKk9YlCcDG0Kk/od6/public/values?alt=json',function(data){
        // loop through the entry object and append new templated elements to body element
        $("body").mustache("listing-template",data.feed.entry);

    });

</script>
```

I left out the initialization details for the mustache framework, but this is the general idea.